# Vue js with Javascript file entegration on CDN type

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

I want to use own js file on my vuejs project. My project is developing on index.html file with vue cdn. How can i added my project another.js file and use in vue instance? Anyone give me suggestion?

Comment: could you explain more ?

Comment: Hello my friend. I have a one-page website. I want to use a javascript file on my site. I have taken an id in my Vuejs design and used it in the vue js file, and I need to return the result and use that result in vuejs. So I need to communicate between Vue js and a javascript file.

Comment: are using vue cli or just cdn by including vue like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>`?

Comment: I could not tell. I'm already using Vue JS. But I couldn't integrate a different javascript file into my project. I couldn't access the functions in the Javascript file.
error when using import argument.

Comment: using vue js cdn or using vue cli?

Comment: i am using vuejs cdn for this project. I haven't any problem with vue-cli

Comment: did you try something like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script><script src="url_to_jsfile.js"></script>`?

Comment: Over the browser you can't use `import`. `import` is Ecmascript code, not Javascript. Ecmascript compiles into Javascript, but isn't runnable in a browser window.